# Group by week day and Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to group data by month and week day

I know this is wrong..

```
select sum(x) from demo_table 
group by DATEPART(month,date) 
where DATENAME(weekday,date)='sunday' ;
```

where clause cannot be used inside group by...
but this is want i need

Comment: you can try `having` instead of `where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
select  sum(x) 
from    demo_table 
where   DATENAME(weekday,date)='sunday'
group by DATEPART(month,date)
```

From [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

> [ WITH common_table_expression]
>
> SELECT select_list [ INTO new_table ]
>
> [ FROM table_source ] [ WHERE search_condition ]
>
> [ GROUP BY group_by_expression ]
>
> [ HAVING search_condition ]
>
> [ ORDER BY order_expression [ ASC | DESC ] ]

Answer (score 1):

Put the `where` clause before the `group by`:

```
select sum(x)
from demo_table
where DATENAME(weekday,date)='sunday'
group by DATEPART(month,date)  ;
```